# Classification of cyclic Galois extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

There are two results that "classify" cyclic Galois extensions of fields.

First one is Lagrange Theorem that holds under certain assumptions:

> Let $K$ be a field $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$.
>
> For $p = Car(K) \neq 0$ (Car = characteristic) we may assume that $p
> \nmid n$.
>
> We assume that there exists $\xi$ a nth root  of unity

Then one has Artin-Schreier theorem that holds under assumptions:

> Let $K$ be a field with $Car(K) = p$ prime

Is it not limiting to assume that there exists $\xi$ a primivite nth root of unity in the base field for the first case?

Comment: Well, yes, of course. It is a very specific situation.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo maybe it is not obvious what i want to point out, the combination of the two theorems should "classify" the cyclic Galois extensions. However, I find this very specific hypothesis as you say in the first case...

Comment: If $L/K$ is Galois cyclic of degree $n$ with $char(K) \nmid n$, then $L(\xi_n)/K(\xi_n)$ is Kummer-cyclic of degree $m | n$ and $L(\xi_n) = K(\xi_n)(a_1^{1/m}, \ldots, a_l^{1/m})$ for some $a_j \in K(\xi_n)$. In general, classifying and constructing the abelian extensions is not so easy and is the purpose of class field theory.

Comment: What the others said. Classifying abelian extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ was a major feat at the time (Kronecker-Weber). Undoubtedly you have seen examples like the followin. If you adjoin $2\cos(2\pi/7)$ to $\Bbb{Q}$ you get a cyclic extension, call it $K$, of degree three. You obviously cannot get $K$ by adjoining a cube root of some rational number. Yet, if we adjoin the same cosine to $\Bbb{Q}(\xi_3)$ we might as well adjoin the cube roots of $14+21\xi_3$. As promised by the first theorem you cited adjoining a cube root is enough! Not at all obvious, took me a while to calculate that :-)